# What does $(\nabla \psi)^2$ mean?

Tags: notation

This is a question about notation. I know that for a function $\psi(x,t)$ $$\nabla\psi=\left(\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x},\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}\right)$$ (the gradient of $\psi$) and $$\nabla^2 \psi=\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial\psi^2}{\partial t^2} $$ (the laplacian of $\psi$).

> By what does $(\nabla \psi)^2$  mean?

Notes

- If $(\nabla \psi)^2$ is another way of representing the laplacian than why didn't they just write $\nabla^2 \psi$ or $\Delta \psi$?
- $K$ is a scalar constant.
- If context is needed see below

[image]

which is from "Novel Methods in Soft Matter Simulations" chapter 29 pg 21

Comment: It is a short-hand notation for the (square of the) norm of $\nabla\psi$. Physicists, right?

Comment: Then why not use $||\nabla \psi||$?

Comment: beats me.${}{}$

Comment: I've seen it used in math texts also but yeah it is definitely common in physics as it just means $\vec{v}^2 = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}$

Comment: So wouldn't it just mean that $(\nabla \psi)^2$=$\nabla^2 \psi$?

Comment: You're right ; It is poor notation for $\nabla \psi \cdot \nabla \psi $.

Comment: $K$ is a scalar constant

Comment: It's usually written $|\nabla \psi|^2$, not $(\nabla\psi)^2$.

Comment: In math I see $| \nabla \psi|$ instead of $\| \nabla \psi \|$ quite often, since the issue of confusing a norm and an absolute value is not really a big deal. But $(\nabla \psi)^2$ is very weird notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\nabla \psi \cdot \nabla \psi=(u_x \hat i+u_y \hat j)
\cdot(u_x\hat i+u_y\hat j)=(u_x)^2+(u_y)^2$.